# Depth is not correct when rotating the camera in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm a newbie in threejs. I have created a sample of the issue so that the issue can be clearly visible.

[Click here to load the sample](https://webhost.mitrmedia.com/webhost/sample/3js/index.html).

In this sample, if you drag the stage horizontally, you'll see that the cube is rotating and so the capsules. But the red capsule is always on top. When the red capsule is smaller than the yellow one that means the red capsule is behind the yellow one. But still the red one is on the top. May be I'm doing some silly stuff here.

Thanks to Marquizzo. [Click here to see the code](https://webhost.mitrmedia.com/webhost/sample/3js/js/index.js).

Comment: Please show your code in the question itself so others can help you find where the mistake took place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved at the [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/depth-is-not-correct-when-rotating-the-camera-in-threejs/12168). The problem was this line of code:

```
 renderer.context.disable(renderer.context.DEPTH_TEST);
```

which disabled depth testing and caused the strange rendering.

`three.js R112`